# Is there an equivalent to WP_Error object I can return in the case of a successful REST request?

Tags: php, rest-api, http, wp-error

In the case of an error at a REST endpoint I've set up, I am accustomed to returning a `WP_Error` object, which is convenient because I can include a code, a message, and an HTTP status into a single returned object.

But what about in the case of success? Is there an equivalent class, for the sake of control and uniformity?

I'm looking at the constructors of `WP_HTTP_Response` and `WP_HTTP_Requests` but they don't seem to accept the same parameters as `WP_Error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`WP_REST_Response`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_response/).